# accept() returning "0" zero (stdin fd) in c socket prog

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I am trying to create server which accepts multiple clients using c socket prog. but manytimes when client connects, `sockfd=accept()` returns 0 (zero) which is `stdin` fd.

As far as I know file descriptor returns minimum value which not in use, so it may returning 0 . But when I try to listen on sockfd (which is 0) or `send()` to `sockfd` it do nothing and both returns 0.

How can I overcome this?

I am working on RaspberryPi Raspbian (debian).

Comment: Have you *closed* `STDIN_FILENO` (or `stdin`)? It's very common to do when daemonizing a server program. Can you please show some code, preferably a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Now that I read again the question after answering it, it is clear that a MCVE is needed :/

Answer (score 3):

It is behaviour on POSIX that the file descriptor returned from a function is the smallest available file descriptor. If you've closed `STDIN_FILENO` or `stdin`, then `0` could be available, and would be the one returned by `connect`.

Note that there is nothing special about file descriptor 0; that it is used for standard input is just a convention only; and `accept`(2) manual on Linux explicitly uses the word *nonnegative* which includes the possibility of it returning `0`:

> **RETURN VALUE**
>
> On success, these system calls return a **nonnegative** integer that is a descriptor for the accepted socket.  **On error, -1 is returned**, and errno is set appropriately.

---

You can avoid this by not closing `STDIN_FILENO`, but opening say `/dev/null` for reading and dup2:n this file descriptor to `STDIN_FILENO` (error checking omitted for brevity):

```
int fd = open("/dev/null", O_RDONLY);
dup2(fd, STDIN_FILENO);
close(fd);
```

(or closing `STDIN_FILENO` and then immediately afterwards opening `/dev/null`, but this is a bit obscure):

```
close(STDIN_FILENO);
open("/dev/null", O_RDONLY);
```

---

I am not sure what you mean by `listen`; a connected TCP socket couldn't be **`listen`ed**. Also, `0` from `send` would mean that you're explicitly sending 0 bytes; because on error `-1` would be returned instead.

Comment: Thnks Antti,  its not 'listen' its 'recv()', srry for that. accpet() returning '0' & showing connected successfully but when  i am trying to recv() not able to receive any data from client.